# how to run the timer in background ? Flutter

Tags: flutter, timer, background-process, clock, foreground

I have a call between two users that will be within specific duration (example 30 mins)
The problem is using the timer will work perfectly in the (foreground when the app open) but in the background of the app the timer will stop.

I tried "`flutter_background_service`" package to run the timer in the background
but it stops at some time, and work again whenever the app opens (Testing on **iPhone**)

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<bool> onStart(ServiceInstance serviceInstance) async {
  if (serviceInstance is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    serviceInstance.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      serviceInstance.setAsForegroundService();
    });

    serviceInstance.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      serviceInstance.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }
  serviceInstance.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    serviceInstance.stopSelf();
  });

  // bring to foreground
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
    if (serviceInstance is AndroidServiceInstance) {
      if (await serviceInstance.isForegroundService()) {
    
        serviceInstance.setForegroundNotificationInfo(
          title: "My App Service",
          content: "Updated at ${DateTime.now()}",
        );
      }
    }

    print("BACKGROUND RUNNGIN ${DateTime.now().second}");
    serviceInstance.invoke(
      'update',
      {
        "current_date": DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
        // "device": ,
      },
    );
  });
  print("BACKGROUND test");
  return true;
}
```

logs

[image: The seconds will stop, and continue working after opening the application]

is there any suitable solution to maintain the timer in the background like other applications in flutter?